# Как получить номер из объявления на olx?

Tags: php, парсер

Я хочу спарсить нужные мне объявления Olx и получить все данные, включая номер. Для того чтобы там получить номер нужно быть авторизированым и нажать на кнопку "Показать номер". Не могу найти способ решить две эти задачи. Во первых как авторизироваться там, ведь на страницы авторизации есть капча, второй вопрос как мне заставить скрипт curl нажимать на кнопку?

Объявления я паршу с помощью curl и xpath.

Comment: если там нет api, то гугель капчу тебе никак не побороть.

Comment: api там есть, читай его.

Comment: @Jean-Claude это не ответ, думаете я не читал api? Кто по вашему будет просто так давать возможность парсить свои данные?

Comment: @Jean-Claude хотя есть рабочие парсеры, вот я и хочу узнать как это делают они.

Comment: ну так для этого напиши код, если возникнут ошибки, поможем.

Comment: @Jean-Claude в этом и проблема что я не понимаю в какую сторону сейчас двигаться. Что писать и что делать.

Comment: и что конкретно тогда вы хотите от нас? ну вот раздел по парсингу веб https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.curl.php